# java: jTabbedPane clicked event in child jTextPane disables jTextPane scrollable setting

Tags: java, jtextpane, jtabbedpane, autoscroll

I have a SSCCE here: A jTabbedPane with a jTextField that when you press cr it will print 20 numbered lines in the jTextpane(inside a jScrollpan). I set autoscroll in the jTextpane. Press cr several time and you will see it scroll. Now click in the jTextPane and go back and to the jTextField and press cr. Scrollable setting is gone.

```
package scrollissue;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret;
import javax.swing.text.Document;


public class ScrollIssue extends JFrame {
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    TopJFrame = new ScrollIssue();
    TopJFrame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(900,600));
    TopJFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    TopJFrame.setVisible(true);

    TopJFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}


static ScrollIssue TopJFrame;
static JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
static Document serialDocument;
static JTextField COMTextField;

public ScrollIssue() {
createNewTab();
getContentPane().add(tabbedPane);
}

public void createNewTab() {
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
panel.add(new JScrollPane(textPane), BorderLayout.CENTER);
tabbedPane.addTab("COM Tab", panel);
tabbedPane.setFocusable(false);
tabbedPane.setAutoscrolls(true);
serialDocument = textPane.getDocument();
COMToolBar COMtoolBar = new COMToolBar(textPane);
panel.add(COMtoolBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

}

class COMToolBar extends JToolBar implements ActionListener {
// COMTextField should be only focus target
// This is enter, Send text to serial port
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String str = ScrollIssue.COMTextField.getText();
// Output no matter what but don't save CR's below
// For each cr send 1/2 a screen full
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        str=str+i+"x \n";
    }
    addStringToSerialDocument(str);
}

public COMToolBar (final JTextPane textPane) {

textPane.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16));
textPane.setBackground(Color.black);
textPane.setForeground(Color.YELLOW); // this is text color!

// Set the textPane to autoscroll
DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret)textPane.getCaret();
caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
// Only want jTextField focusable
textPane.setFocusable(false);
textPane.setAutoscrolls(true);
textPane.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
// Terminal window is not editable - output only.
textPane.setEditable(false); // keys sent to the serial port, echoed back
//  ScrollIssue.COMTextField.requestFocusInWindow();

COMTextField = new JTextField(92); // number is column SUGGESTION not LIMIT!!
COMTextField.setFocusable(true);
COMTextField.requestFocusInWindow();
add(COMTextField);

// This is only way to guarantee COMTextField input/CR fires.
// THIS IS REQUIRED!!!!!!!!!!!!
COMTextField.addActionListener(this);

}
public void addStringToSerialDocument(String s){
try {
 serialDocument.insertString(serialDocument.getLength(), s, null);

} catch(BadLocationException ex) {
        System.out.println("Caught serialDocument.insertString err in addStringToSerialDocument\n"+ex);
}
}

}
} // END of class ScrollIssue extends JFrame
```

So when a mouse click or tab key advances to the jTextPane the scrollable attribute is lost.

This doesn't work. I have not found a not clickable setting for the jTextPane.

So my question: is there a display only always scroll-able component I should be using? The "view" related components did not appear to me to be for my needs. Am I wrong?

Or is this a matter of catching tab into/click into events to simple return the focus to the jTextField?

Please don't tell me the jTextPane click sets a cursor that I have to handle just to maintain the user illision of a auto scroll display!

Well yes tell me if so.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question then check out [Text Area Scrolling](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/22/text-area-scrolling/) for a solution.

Basically you should be able to use:

```
 JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
 DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret)textPane.getCaret();
 caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
```

Edit:

Hmm, your SSCCE doesn't work (as expected) and my old examples don't seem to work either. So it seems the using the setUpdatePolicy(...) approach no longer works.

So the suggestions would be:

1. Use the `setCaretPosition(...)` method of the JTextPane after adding text to the text pane
2. Or, you might want to try the [Smart Scrolling](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/03/03/smart-scrolling/). When the scrollbar is add the bottom and text is added then scrolling will be automatic. However, if the user moves the scrollbar then automatic scrolling will stop until the scrollbar is moved back to the bottom.

Comment: @ClydeW.PhillipsJr., Then post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I'll have to architect a SSCCE as my current code requires a serial conversation to reveal the issue. A simple jTabbedPane with an append text to a jTextPane button may do it.

Comment: I have a SSCCE but it is too long to past in this comment. How do I share it?

Comment: @ClydeW.PhillipsJr., A SSCCE should always be included with your question. You can edit the question to add the code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by setting the caret position of the JTextPane after inserting string into it's document.

```
public void addStringToSerialDocument(String s){
try {
serialDocument.insertString(serialDocument.getLength(), s, null);
// Reset caret to preserve scrolling!
COMTextPane.setCaretPosition(serialDocument.getLength());

} catch(BadLocationException ex) {
        System.out.println("Caught serialDocument.insertString err"+ex);
}
}
```